# Split values for columns in CSV file using Python

Tags: python, csv, flask

```
import urllib
import csv

@manager.command
def list_routes():
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        options = {}

    for arg in rule.arguments:
        options[arg] = "[{0}]".format(arg)

    url = rule.rule
    line = urllib.parse.unquote("{}{} ".format(rule.endpoint, url))

    with open('urls.cvs', 'a') as out:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(out, lineterminator='', dialect='excel')
        spamwriter.writerows(line)
        spamwriter.writerows('\n')
```

I need to fill in the csv file so that rule.endpoint and url have separate columns.

Comment: you have incorrect indentions.

Comment: Try `line = urllib.parse.unquote("{},{} ".format(rule.endpoint, url))` and then `writerow` instead of `writerows`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
@manager.command
def list_routes():
    with open('urls.csv', 'w') as out:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(out, lineterminator='\n')
        csv_writer.writerows([[rule.endpoint, rule.rule] for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules()])
```

Answer (score 3):

Your [`writerows`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) parameter just needs to be a list of lists of the values the row should contain. So for example `writer.writerows([[1, 2], [3, 4]])` will add two rows where each row contains two values. As you add only one row you can use `writerow`:

```
spamwriter.writerow([rule.endpoint, url])
```

Here is a mock-up. I'm using `BytesIO` so that I don't need to actually write to a file:

```
import csv
import io
c = io.BytesIO()
w = csv.writer(c, lineterminator="", dialect="excel")
w.writerow(['endpoint', 'url'])
print(c.getvalue())  # prints: endpoint,url
```

Comment: Could you be more specific what you get and what you expect? I tested it and it seemed to work for me.